# Binding to Self/'this' in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Simple WPF/XAML question. In XAML, how do I reference the Self/this object in a given context? In a very basic app with a main window, one control, and a coded C# property of the window, I want to bind a property of the control to the hand coded property of the window.

In code, this is very easy - in the Window's constructor, I added this:

```
Binding bind = new Binding();
bind.Source = this;
bind.Path = new PropertyPath("ButtonWidth");
button1.SetBinding(WidthProperty, bind);
```

Obviously, I have a property called ButtonWidth, and a control called button1. I can't figure out how to do this in XAML. Various attempts like the following example have not worked:

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Width="{Binding Source=Self Path=ButtonWidth}"/>

<Button x:Name="button1" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self} Path=ButtonWidth}"/>
```

etc

Thanks

Answer (score 92, accepted):

First use a comma between the RelativeSource and Path in your Binding:

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                                Path=ButtonWidth}"/>
```

Secondly, the RelativeSource binds to the Button. Button has no property called ButtonWidth. I am guessing you need to Bind to your parent control.

So try this RelativeSource binding:

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Width="{Binding RelativeSource=
    {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type YourNamespace:YourParentControl}}, 
    Path=ButtonWidth}"/>
```

Comment: I have a DataGrid where if the user accesses one of its inline ContextMenu's MenuItem's Command's via an InputBinding's KeyBinding whose CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid, Path=SelectedItems}", it'll pass the SelectedItems to the Bound ICommand. However, null is passed if it's accessed via the ContextMenu. I've tried CommandParameter= "{Binding SelectedItems}", "{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid, Path=SelectedItems}", "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=SelectedItems}".  I did set the CommandParameter prior to the Command.

Comment: answer is correct, upvoted, because it works. but apparently this is another example of "xaml syntax sugar"...

Answer (score 43):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
<Window x:Class = "blah blah all the regular stuff"

DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"

>
```

Comment: Verified still works on Windows 10 app in the <Page> main element.

Answer (score 30):

One way I get around having to deal with RelativeSource and the like is to name the root XAML element:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    x:Name="_this"
    >
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Width="{Binding ElementName=_this,Path=ButtonWidth}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If you want to set the DataContext you could also do this:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    x:Name="_this"
    >
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_this}">        
        <Button x:Name="button" Width="{Binding Path=ButtonWidth}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I find this to be a good trick to not have to remember all the complexities of the RelativeSource binding.

Answer (score 4):

The problem [with naming the `XAML` root element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4308569/3195477) is that, if you get into the habit of using the same name (i.e, "_this", "Root", etc.) for all the roots in your project, then late-binding in nested templates may access the wrong element. This is because, when `{Binding}` `ElementName=...` is used in a `Template`, names are resolved at runtime by walking up the `NameScope` tree until the first match is found.

[Clint's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13275276/3195477) avoids naming the root element, but it sets the root element into its own `DataContext`, which might not be an option if the DataContext is needed for, say, data. It also seems a bit heavy-handed to introduce another binding on an element just for the purpose of providing access to it. Later, if access is no longer needed, that `{Binding}` will become clutter: responsibility for access properly belongs with the target and binding.

Accordingly, here is a simple markup extension to access the XAML root element without naming it:

```
using System.Xaml;
using System.Windows.Markup;

public sealed class XamlRootExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public override Object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        var rop = sp.GetService(typeof(IRootObjectProvider)) as IRootObjectProvider;
        return rop == null ? null : rop.RootObject;
    }
};
```

**XAML**:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:global="clr-namespace:">

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={global:XamlRoot},Mode=OneTime}" />

</Window>
```

*note*: for clarity, I didn't define the `MarkupExtension` in a namespace; using an empty `clr-namespace` alias as shown here *d̲o̲e̲s̲* actually work in for accessing the `global::` namespace (although the VS2013 designer seems to complains about it).

**Result**:

[image]
*A window whose content is bound to itself.*

---

**n.b.**

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, naming the root element with "ElementName=.." seems to be the only way with UWP as {RelativeSource Self} is not supported there.

Oddly enough, this still works when the name is overrid in layout, e.g.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Path.MyClass" x:Name="internalName">
   <Border Background={Binding Path=Background, ElementName=internalName}" ...
```

then

```
<Page>
   <local:MyClass x:Name=externalName />

</Page>
```

BTW, Windows 10 fixed an error (present at Windows 8.1), when same internal name is used for different elements in same layout.

Still, I would prefer to use {RelativeSource Self}, since it appears more logical and safer to me.