# UWP Xaml Textblock Data Binding - UI not updating even though the property is updated

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp, inotifypropertychanged

Firstly a Disclaimer: I have read dozens of posts with hundreds of answers and yet I have not found a solution.  I have attempted to resolve this every which way I can find and yet the UI does not update.

I am writing a UWP app as a personal project.  In this particular scenario I have a Grid with an assigned DataContext with a series of TextBlocks which are Bound to Properties.  I am using "Binding" and not "x:Bind" due to the Grid been part of a ControlTemplate.

- I have implemented the Properties with INotifyPropertyChanged.
- I have backing fields.
- I have stepped through the debugging and the Properties are updated and retain the values assigned.
- I have tried using UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged.
- I have tried different Modes - OneWay/TwoWay etc.

The issue:  The UI completely ignores the changes and NEVER updates.

I have set the properties with a value within the Page Constructor, and that is set, but no changes thereafter are applied... EVER.

Please see the relevant code snippets below and maybe someone can see something I have not.

Thanks in advance.

Grid XAML:

```
<Grid
    Grid.Row="1"
    BorderBrush="{StaticResource SystemControlChromeLowAcrylicElementBrush}"
    BorderThickness="2,0,2,2">
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <views:MenusPage />
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="152" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="152" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="152" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="152" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="152" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Padding="15,0,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Text="Totals" />

    <Border
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="3"
        Margin="0,2,0,-2"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource SystemControlChromeLowAcrylicElementBrush}"
        BorderThickness="2,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock
            Padding="10,0,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Text="{Binding CaloriesTotal, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Border>
    <Border
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="4"
        Margin="0,2,0,-2"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource SystemControlChromeLowAcrylicElementBrush}"
        BorderThickness="2,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock
            Padding="10,0,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Text="{Binding ProteinTotal}" />
    </Border>
    <Border
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="5"
        Margin="0,2,0,-2"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource SystemControlChromeLowAcrylicElementBrush}"
        BorderThickness="2,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock
            Padding="10,0,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Text="{Binding FatTotal}" />
    </Border>
    <Border
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="6"
        Margin="0,2,0,-2"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource SystemControlChromeLowAcrylicElementBrush}"
        BorderThickness="2,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock
            Padding="10,0,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Text="{Binding CarbTotal}" />
    </Border>
    <Border
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="7"
        Margin="0,2,0,-2"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource SystemControlChromeLowAcrylicElementBrush}"
        BorderThickness="2,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock
            Padding="15,0,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Text="{Binding SugarTotal}" />
    </Border>

</Grid>
```

Properties:

```
private double _caloriesTotal;
public double CaloriesTotal
{
    get { return _caloriesTotal; }
    set { Set(ref _caloriesTotal, value); }
}

private double _proteinTotal;
public double ProteinTotal
{
    get { return _proteinTotal; }
    set { Set(ref _proteinTotal, value); }
}

private double _fatTotal;
public double FatTotal
{
    get { return _fatTotal; }
    set { Set(ref _fatTotal, value); }
}

private double _carbTotal;
public double CarbTotal
{
    get { return _carbTotal; }
    set { Set(ref _carbTotal, value); }
}

private double _sugarTotal;
public double SugarTotal
{
    get { return _sugarTotal; }
    set { Set(ref _sugarTotal, value); }
}
```

PropertyChanged:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
{
    if (Equals(storage, value))
    {
        return;
    }

    storage = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
}

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

Code Setting the values:
(NOTE: this is the shortened version but the same effect applies, setting the values in the constructor applies the values and UI updates but setting the values anywhere else on the page, within any method that is executed, they are ignored and the UI shows zeros.)

```
CaloriesTotal = 10;
ProteinTotal = 20;
FatTotal = 30;
CarbTotal = 40;
SugarTotal = 50;
```

Comment: That's a really interesting implementation for your `set` on each property. What is `propertyName` when your `Set` method gets called, is it null or the correct property name?

Comment: @jsmyth886 the property name is passed correctly and value that is populated is correct everytime.  I have even tried the same configuration stipulated in Microsoft docs and where you pass the string value of the and still, the property is updated but not the UI

It makes no sense at all.

Stepping through the code shows the values are set on the properties.

Comment: hmm, I've just tried your implementation and it works for me. However I'm using the Caliburn Framework which already has an implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` so I just called that in the `Set`. Are there any `Binding` errors in the output window when you Debug?

Comment: @jsmyth886  just run through the debug to be sure, no errors show up

Comment: Is it possible that `MenusPage` is being created twice, but only being attached once to the `Grid`, hence it looking like the properties are changing in code but not actually notifying the UI because a different instance is attached to the `Grid`? Without seeing more of the code it's pretty difficult to figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, and while I am dumbfounded as to how it actually worked while the other 'normal' solutions that should have worked did not, is beyond me.

Anyway thanks to @jsmyth886 and @Alexey for your help and suggestions in troubleshooting.

Since posting this question I have tried separating out the properties into another class, referencing `<Models:MenuTypesModel x:Key="MenuTotals" />` within the `<Page.Resources>` block **-- failed**

I Tried setting the `DataContext` of the `Page` itself **-- failed**

The `<Grid> ... </Grid>` XAML in my question is, as said, part of a `ControlTemplate` I even moved the block out of the Control Template and onto the Page itself to eliminate any clashing with other datasources - mind you all different naming structures and paths, so ultimately should not have clashed -- this did not work either, so **-- failed**

It was @Alexey response that got me thinking in a different line and my searching ultimately led me to this post [Binding to Self/'this' in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837755/binding-to-self-this-in-xaml/4308569#4308569) which solved my problem.

I removed the following datacontext from the Grid:

```
<Grid.DataContext>
    <views:MenusPage />
</Grid.DataContext>
```

And replaced it with this `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_this}"` and made sure of my textblock bindings, the end result (Very Short Version):

```
<Grid ... DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_this}">
    ...
    <TextBlock ... Text="{Binding CaloriesTotal}" />
    ...
</Grid>
```

And finally added the a Name attribute to the Page itself:

```
x:Name="_this"
```

And it worked!!!!

I have changes nothing in the way I have set my properties.

My properties are still defined as per the question, I have no viewmodels or additional classes, nor am I setting DataContext in the CodeBehind.

Simply adding `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_this}"`the grid and `x:Name="_this"` to the Page allows the UI to reflect the changes to the properties every time.

An oddly simple solution.

A NOTE: though, while I was trying different things though, when I had the Grid on the page itself outside of the ContentTemplate, I set the DataContext of the page in codebehind `DataContext = this;` and it started populating but still failed to affect the Grid in the Control template.

So unless there is a clash that I didn't see or because I have other DataSources which are unrelated as well as assigned directly the to control that needs it... I cannot figure why it works now with this simple binding.

Anyway, thanks for the assistance and I hope this helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to benefit from NavigationCacheMode (Enabled/Required) for the sake of performance, you have to update the bindings on data context change.

```
 public MainPage()
 {
      this.InitializeComponent();

      this.DataContextChanged += (s, e) => this.Bindings.Update();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use binding DataContext for your main object, not for DataGrid:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <views:MenusPage />
</Window.DataContext>
```

Comment: Changing the `DataContext` of the `Grid` should be no problem. I'll also point out that the tag `<Window></Window>` isn't part of UWP.

Comment: @jsmyth886 what is the root element? use it instead of Grid, and put these lines right away in this root element

Comment: @Alexey  I had given your suggestion another shot and it failed as well, still no go.